# Custom templates for posts like for pages: page-{id} vs single-{id}

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

If I'm understanding correctly, I can create a custom template for a specific page by creating a file called `page-{my_page_title_or_id)`, which gets displayed when visiting that page. I can also create a custom template for pages by adding `Template Name: My Page Type` in the header comments.

However, the situation with posts seems very different. As far as I can tell, creating a file called `single-{post_title_or_id)` doesn't force display of that file for the given post. It appears to do nothing at all.

I understand that I can create a custom post type and display instances of that with `single-{post_type_name}`, which is great. However, if I want to create a template for just one particular post, it seems like overkill, and I would have to include conditional logic for when the id/title of the post matched the onle I want to display.

Am I missing something here? Is my understanding of the situation correct? Please can someone tell me the most simple way to display a custom view for a post with a given title/id?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### A) Single Post Templates: `single-{post-type}-{post-name}.php`

It's informative to check out the [`get_single_template()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_single_template/) function.

There we find the following template possibilities:

```
"single-{$object->post_type}-{$object->post_name}.php"
"single-{$object->post_type}.php"
"single.php"
```

In WordPress 4.7 this part will be added:

```
"single-{$object->post_type}-{$name_decoded}.php"
```

So it looks like you forgot the `{$object->post_type}` part in the template's name.

**Example:**

The *single* template name for the *post* with the slug `hello-world`:

```
single-post-hello-world.php
```

### B) Custom Single Post Templates

Another feature in WordPress 4.7 will be the support for *custom single post templates*.

Check out ticket [#18375](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18375) for more info.

**Example:**

I just tested this new feature, by creating a template file, e.g. `tpl-wpse-test.php`, in the current theme directory:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name:      WPSE Template Test
 * Template Post Type: post
 */
 get_header();
 ?><div id="main"> WPSE Template Test - Success! ;-) </div><?php
 get_footer();
```

Then the  following meta box shows up automatically in the backend for the corresponding post types.

[image: Metabox]

There's a multi post type support as well, e.g.:

```
 * Template Post Type: posttype1, posttype2, posttype3
```

But there's no need to use `add_theme_support()`, like we use to get the *featured image* meta box.