# Custom post type , page template not grabbing the page template

Tags: custom-post-types, page-template

[image]

I had created the custom post type , and added page-attributes to the register_post_type, and created a page ( foo ) and added the page slug to the page template with `page-slug.php`. The page template is displaying in the page ( foo ) I created but not in the custom post type the above image shows in the custom post type.

When i selected the page template in the page panel the template is not grabbed. But the post i created is displayed in the page(foo) with default `content.php` template part

Comment: This is expected behaviour, only pages have page templates by default. `page-slug.php` will only work with pages, similar to how `post-slug.php` will only work with posts. Have you consulted the template hierarchy diagrams?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/244373/26350) can help?

Comment: Take a look into [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oabaP.png) graph, as @TomJNowell mentioned.